# Sequence of differentiable functions converging to non-differentiable function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Purely out of interest, I wanted to try and construct a sequence of differentiable functions converging to a non-differentiable function. I began with the first non-differentiable function that sprung to my mind, namely
\begin{align}
&f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\\
&f(x)=|x|.
\end{align}
After some testing I considered the function defined by
$$f_\varepsilon(x) = |x|+\frac{\varepsilon}{|x|+\sqrt{\varepsilon}} $$
for some $\varepsilon>0$. Then $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0^+}f_\varepsilon(x)=f(x)$, and $f_\varepsilon(x)$ *looks* smooth, i.e. differentiable for every $\varepsilon>0$ on the entire domain.

**Question:** How can I prove that $f_\varepsilon$ is differentiable for every $\varepsilon>0$ (or disprove) using the definition of the derivative?

If this assertion is true, then I construct the sequence simply by setting $\varepsilon = 1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Attempt:** I set up the definition for the derivative
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}f_\varepsilon}{\mathrm{d}x} &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left[\left(|x+h|+\frac{\varepsilon}{|x+h|+\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\right)-\left(|x|+\frac{\varepsilon}{|x|+\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\right)\right]\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left[|x+h|-|x|+\frac{\varepsilon}{|x+h|+\sqrt{\varepsilon}}-\frac{\varepsilon}{|x|+\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\right],
\end{align}
but I could not figure out how to proceed.

**Sidenotes:** An interesting thing I discovered when constructing $f_\varepsilon$, was that almost any small change removes its smoothness, for example
\begin{equation}
g_\varepsilon(x) = |x|+\frac{2\varepsilon}{|x|+\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\hspace{2cm} h_\varepsilon(x) = |x|+\frac{\varepsilon}{|x|+2\sqrt{\varepsilon}}
\end{equation}
do both not look smooth at all. Similarly for the other terms; changing the coefficients will remove the smoothness. I am also somewhat intrigued by this. So if anyone can shed some light on this, even better.

Comment: Unrelated to your construction, what about taking $f(x) = |x|$ and fitting it with a polynomial on $[-a,a]$ with a smooth fit, and letting $a\to 0$?

Comment: Interestingly, in Cauchy's _Cours d'Analyse de l'École Polytechnique_ there is a theorem stating that the limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous as well. Abel proved this wrong with the example $f_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{n-1}\frac{\sin nx}{n}$ which converges to a saw-tooth function. If you want to construct your own sequence, I suggest looking at Fourier series.

Comment: @slo Interesting. Right now I am looking mostly at differentiability, not just continuity. Perhaps I will try with Fourier series, but right now I'm interested in the sequence that I chose:
$$f_n(x) = |x|+\frac{n^{-1}}{|x|+n^{-1/2}} $$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence of differentiable functions $h_n(x) = x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}$ defined on $[-1,1]$ and note
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} h_n(x) =
x\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x^\frac{1}{2n-1}=
 |x|,\qquad \forall x\in[-1,1].
$$

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think your function is differentiable? Did you calculate the derivatives? What does the picture look like for $ε=1$ or $ε=10$?

---

An easier differentiable approximation of the abs function is
$$\sqrt{ε^2+x^2}$$ or $$\sqrt{ε^2+x^2}-ε.$$

Differentiability here is obvious by the chain rule.

---

Added: Close to zero, $|x|\lt \sqrt ε$, one can use the binomial formula to get
\begin{align}
|x|+\frac{ε}{|x|+\sqrt{ε}} &= |x|+ε\frac{\sqrt{ε}-|x|}{ε-x^2} =\frac{ε\sqrt{ε}-x^2|x|}{ε-x^2}
\end{align}
which tells that the function is twice continuously differentiable and symmetric at the origin (which we knew before), so that it has horizontal slope there.

Comment: Good idea using $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ as a way to approximate the function, but I'm not looking for another approximating function.

The function *looks* smooth ([plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%7C%2Bepsilon%2F%28%7Cx%7C%2Bsqrt%28epsilon%29%29%2C+where+epsilon%3D10)). Using WolframAlpha:
$$f_\varepsilon'(x) = \frac{x(|x|+2\sqrt{\varepsilon})}{(|x|+\sqrt{\varepsilon})^2} $$
which is a continuous function when $\varepsilon>0$, supporting the idea that $f_\varepsilon\in\mathcal{C}^1$. If you have any tip for calculating the derivative with the definition let me know :-).

Comment: Using the binomial formula, one can find an expression for the original formula with smooth denominator, so that the differentiability can be read off from the numerator.

Comment: I have not gone through the computations yet, but this is closer to what I'm looking for, +1.