# Finding sequence of continuously differentiable functions with bounded derivative that converge to non-differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

I am having some trouble with the following problem, which states the following: Suppose $\{f_n\}, n=0,1,2,...$ is a sequence of continuously differentiable functions $f_n :[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ converging pointwise to $f$, and that there is a constant $M>0$ such that $|f_n'(x) < M|$ holds for all $x \in [0,1]$ and all $n\geq 1$. Give an example of a sequence satisfying all of the above hypothesis for which the limit function is, however, not differentiable. Sketch graphs of a few of the $f_n$'s and the limit function $f$.

Now, I have already established that under the conditions above, $f_n$ actually converges uniformly to $f$. And as a result, $f$ is continuous. I ran across a helpful related question here: [Sequence of differentiable functions converging to non-differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051335/sequence-of-differentiable-functions-converging-to-non-differentiable-function) and the sequence $f_n := \sqrt{ 1/n + (x-1/2)^2}$ is close to what I want, but unfortunately it does not meet the requirement of having some $M>0$ such that$|f_n'(x) < M|$ holds for all $x \in [0,1]$ and all $n\geq 1$. Is there a way to modify this sequence to get the desired result/is there a better example?

I think I can visualize more or less what the solution will require: We want some sequence of functions that are smooth everywhere but for which there is some smooth portion which gets "sharper" as $n$ increases, until it becomes a "corner" in the limit. But I'm having trouble making that happen while satisfying the bounded derivative part of the hypothesis.

Comment: But $$\frac{x - 1/2}{\sqrt{1/n + (x - 1/2)^2}}$$ is bounded by $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: Oh, I made a complete novice mistake and completely forgot about the $x- 1/2$ factor in the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $f_n(x) = (x-\frac{1}{2})^{\large {1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}}=\left((x-\frac{1}{2})^2\right)^{n/(2n-1)}$ which converges to $\left |x-\frac{1}{2}\right| $